# Find the adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

> I would like to find the adjoint operator in the Hilbertspace $L^2(0,\infty)$ of the operator
>   $$
> (Ax)(t)=x(at), x\in L^2(0,\infty), a>0.
> $$

My calculation is the following; I use the substitution $u=at$.

$$
\langle Ax,y\rangle_{L^2}=\int\limits_0^{\infty}x(at)\overline{y(t)}\, dt=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x(u)\overline{\frac{1}{a}y\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)}\, du
$$

So the adjoint operator $A^*\colon L^2(0,\infty)\to L^2(0,\infty)$ should be given by

$$
(A^*x)(u)=\frac{1}{a}x\left(\frac{u}{a}\right).
$$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: And your comment looks good to me. Thank you!

Comment: One thing, in your definition of $A^*x$, you accidentally have a $y$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Oh, I replace it by x.